# Will Lufthansa fly to Belarus from Germany?

Tags: air-travel, germany, eu, belarus

As many of you are already aware, the EU has banned Belavia (the national airline of Belarus) from flying over EU airspace and from landing at EU airports. As of yesterday, Belavia has also [cancelled](https://en.belavia.by/news/4724345/) the Berlin-Minsk route. I had a booking with Belavia from Berlin to Minsk, which got cancelled and since Turkish Airlines is now the only plant that takes passengers from Berlin to Minsk (via Istanbul), they have raised the price three-fold.

The only viable alternative is Lufthansa, which goes to Minsk via Frankfurt. The main issue is: Frankfurt has announced that they will not be flying to Belarusian airspace indefinitely, however you can still purchase tickets from 4th June onwards. I tried to contact Lufthansa 3 times but I was on hold for 10 minutes, 40 minutes and 30 minutes respectively.

Does anyone have more information regarding this issue? Will Lufthansa fly to Belarus or not?

Comment: I don't think it's within any airline's control how the geopolitical situation develops...

Comment: I highly doubt that LH will fly. The EU is making a point here and LH will not undermine that.

Comment: I guess you still can take the train.

Answer (score 5):

Don't put your money on it.

Nobody can tell you what's really going to happen. Only time will tell. But buying an LH ticket on a route that they declared they won't be flying indefinitely is a gamble.

From a quick look at the map, Istanbul looks like a much safer bet.
Flying through Russia can also be an option. Some EU to Russia flights were cancelled due to the same crisis, but some are still flying.

Comment: That is indeed true. Their statement that they will cancel all flights to Minsk and re-route other flights around Belarus and the fact that they still sell tickets to Minsk created a bit of confusion for me. But you are correct - it would be a gamble to buy the tickets right now. I guess the best course would be to wait for further instructions.

Answer (score 5):

At present, all EU based carriers are banned from overflying, and landing in, Belarusian airspace. Belarusian airlines are also banned from overflying, and landing in, EU airspace. Thus there are no direct flights from Minsk to anywhere in the EU.

Russia has also denied entry to an flight from Paris to Moscow, and another from Vienna to Moscow. These flights would have overflown Belarus, but Russia refused the flights' alternative route avoiding Belarus.

To get from Belarus to the EU, the most sensible (even though it's a long way around) is to travel through either Istanbul or Moscow. This assumes that there are no COVID-related restrictions on your proposed flight. Your other option is to try the land crossings, but that will need to be researched first.

Comment: Unfortunately, all land borders of Belarus (except for the one with Russia) are also closed. But regarding your first point, have EU carriers been officially banned from flying to Belarus or have they been advised to not allow flights to Belarus?

Comment: Neither. They have chosen to not fly there by themselves, to make a point.